# Simple dropdow to change "status" for content filed with node reference

Tags: drupal

I want to do a simple thing but it's driving me crazy. I have two content types: student and courses. I have a field on my student's content type with which the admin can select wich courses belongs to an student (Student do Course I, Course II, etc)...this is simple because i'm using "node reference" for the content populated with course content type...but i need to give an status to particular courses, i.e "John is in Pachwork course and has paid for it"....so, summarizing, i need when the admin chose a course for a student appears a combobox-dropdow to select if paid or not that particular course...but i'm trying to do that all the afternoon but i can't accomplished anything good. Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: so do you have a boolean column in your Student cck?

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest dev of CCK 3 and its multigroup module, set up a multigroup consisting of a nodereference and its status (a selectlist or taxonomy term).